# What is "apartment landing"?

Tags: meaning

Context:

> "He's always been very polite and very quiet, though I didn't know him well. He always wore a tie, would walk to work. Nothing about him was particularly outstanding," she said on the **apartment landing**. She declined to give her last name.

What is "apartment landing"?

Comment: The landing is the area at the top of the staircase which has rooms leading off it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the place near to the staircase or a place between two sets of staircases.

> [landing](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/landing): *the area at the top of a set of stairs where you arrive before you go into an upstairs room or move onto another set of stairs.*

She was standing there while giving that statement.

See [the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrR8AWIuc7A). In the very first scene, the girl is reading **on the landing**.

The apartment with such structure is called *Landing Apartment*

[image]

Comment: This is a fine answer, but generally speaking, I would expect the term "landing apartment" to be one whose entrance comes off of the *building landing*, not one possessing a landing. It's entirely normal for a living space with stairs to have a landing built in. In American usage, at least, nobody would find it remarkable enough to comment on.